# in angular, How would I access a controller defined in one module, in a link function defined in a directive in another module

Tags: angularjs

Right now I'm driving myself nuts trying to find an easy way to do this, but I'm working with some very old code I can do very little to re-arrange, and as it stands I have a controller

`angular.module('a.module').controller('SomeController'...`

and a directive defined like

```
angular.module('b.module', ['a.module'])
angular.module('b.module').directive('aDirective', () => {
  return: {   
    controller: (scope) => {....},
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) {...}
  }
});
```

from within the link function of the directive in module b., I want to access SomeController and its functions.  I have tried the $directive service with no luck, and not sure I can do much with the directive having the controller defined.

Comment: Why can you not just inject someController?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DOM structure and what exactly you are trying to access/pass, one possible option could be to use isolated scope if your directive is a child of the element bound to the controller. You would provide the methods and/or data from the controller to your directive using the isolated scope modifiers "@", "=" or "&", like so:

```
angular.module('a.module').controller('SomeController', [
    '$scope',

    function ($scope) {
      $scope.text = "This is my text";

      $scope.func = function() {
        alert("Called from a.module");
      }
    }
]);

angular.module('b.module').directive('aDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      text: "@",
      func: "&"
    },
    template: '<div ng-click="func()">{{ dir }}</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dir = scope.text;
    }
  }
})
```

and the DOM:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
  <a-directive func="func()" text="{{ text }}"></a-directive>
</div>
```

Here's a sample Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/kGicc8h79DGn1QvmjJzg

However, use this approach sparingly and only if you're trying to give your directive some specific behavior. If you have business logic in your controller that could/should be used by other controllers or directives, don't keep it in the controllers. Instead, extract those functions into a service and inject the service into your directives/controllers.